# Best practices for dealing with exceptions in a synchronized block/method in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have read that we must be careful while coding synchronized blocks or methods because if a thread exits from a synchronized method/block because of an exception, the synchronization lock is released cause the memory model couldn't care less about whether a thread exited because of an exception. So the synchronization lock is going to be available for grabs by other threads even though the object might be in a corrupted state.

So if we consider best practices, are there any guidelines that we could follow for writing synchronized methods/blocks. Personally I think locks are quite good because of their try {} finally {} semantics but if we have an API that needs to absolutely have the synchronized methods/blocks, what would be a good approach of coding these synchronized methods/blocks. I thought that it might be good to also employ the try finally approach for the synchronized methods but then the StringBuffer class does not use that approach. I'm not sure if any of the standard classes that have synchronized methods use that approach. So then should leaving the logging part to an uncaughtExceptionHandler be the way out?

Are there any other good practices that could come in handy? Is there a way to prevent other threads from acquiring the synchronization lock, should an object's state get corrupted. UncaughtExceptionHandlers and finally blocks can at the most perform additional logging. Would that be right? They can't really prevent other threads from subsequently acquiring the synchronization lock. Would that be right? So then how should we code the synchronized methods/blocks in Java?

Comment: Can you give an example? Why do you want to prevent that other threads can acquire the lock if a lock has been released due to a thrown exception?

Comment: This question is too broad for StackOverflow. A good answer would be a chapter or two in a book.

Comment: Because the exception could have caused the object to be in a corrupted state. For example, let us say I have a synchronized method that debits an account. Say there was some RuntimeException that went uncaught. The thread died and the UncaughtExceptionHandler logged it. But now another thread tries to perform a debit again or a credit again. It will get the lock. I think I cannot prevent that from happening, but I am not sure. I know I can perform logging. But is that all I could do. My question is general from best practices point of view - should we code the logic in try finally blocks.

Comment: I thought as such but I wasn't sure. Will try to refer to books. Thanks for going through my question.

Comment: You should read about [Exception safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety). An exception should never leave an object in an inconsistent state.

Comment: At a fundamental level, this is what try/catch is for.  When an exception occurs, the catch/finally logic is responsible for restoring a consistent state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Critical sections (a.k.a., "synchronized blocks") can be very detrimental to the performance of your application.  Learn about Amdahl's Law.  Each time you start to write "synchronized," you should ask yourself, "can I re-design to eliminate the need?"†  If the answer is no, then your next question should be, "how can I make it as small as possible?"

If the code in your synchronized block can throw an exception, then it probably is not as small as possible.  Find a way to do the exception-throwing-thing without touching the global state, and then only enter the synchronized block to modify the state if the exception-throwing-thing produced a valid result.

If it sounds like I am asking you to write a program that does extra work, it's because I *am* asking you to write a program that does extra work.  The message of Amdahl's Law is that we often have to do things in a way that would be less-than-optimal on a uni-processor machine in order to get the best performance from a multi-processor machine.

multi-processing has been around for a while, but wide-spread deployment of multi-processing architectures is new.  People are still using books that were written when "multi-processor" meant "supercomputer."  But all of a sudden, we've got laptops with four and eight cores, and even cell phones have multiple cores.

It's time to stop doing things the old way.

---

† java.util.concurrent classes are your friends.